# Passport or driver license when travelling from California to Seattle?

Tags: usa, passports, us-citizens, domestic-travel

Do I need my passport to travel from California to Seattle?
I'm planning to travel on October 7,  2019.

I need an answer if I don't need my passport to travel seattle or do I just need ID to present to travel Seattle.

I am US citizen.

Comment: *How* do you intend to travel? By car, bus, train or airplane?

Comment: If you aren't as white as snow you may wish to carry a passport anyway. ICE has actually deported American citizens for the crime of not having a passport on them while not being white.

Answer (score 1):

For travel in 2019, you will only require your Drivers License, regardless of how you plan to travel.  There is absolutely no need for a US citizen to carry their passport for this trip.

Beginning October 1, **2021** there MAY be a need to carry your passport if you are flying.  This is the current start date for the requirement to have a [REAL ID](https://www.dhs.gov/real-id) complaint ID in order to fly.  If your Drivers License is REAL ID Compliant (most California drivers licences are NOT - other states will vary) then even from this date you will be fine with just a drivers license.

However if your drivers license is NOT REAL ID Compliant, then from this date you will require a passport or other suitable ID - at least in theory.  (Exactly how this ends up being implemented, and what will happen for people without such ID, is at this stage unknown)